# Jenkins Publish HTML report does not publish html reports

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to Publish HTML reports generated from my newman scripts and using the following settings in Jenkins job.

```
    HTML directory to archive   : ./newman
    Index page[s]   : myReport.html
    Report title    : My Report
```

I am generating the newman reports in /newman directory in my workspace. However, on the project dashboard, I am able to see the link to the report but as I click on it, it shows an error in processing the report because "" not found. Why is this trying to read the report from an incorrect directory?

There is a message in console output:

```
    Archiving HTML reports...
    [htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level 
    /export/jenkins_slave/workspace/<teamPath>/ProjectName/newman to 
    /net/<company name>/jenkins_homes/<team path with 
    /job>/<ProjectName>/builds/2/htmlreports/ReportFolder
```

Recording test results

script:

```
            always {

            sh label: '', script: '''cd /target
                                tar -czf report.html output'''

            emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/target/report.html', body: '''CreateProject_Pipeline - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

                                            ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}

                                            Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.''', 
                                            recipientProviders: [requestor()], subject: 'VDP_CreateProject_Pipeline-API Test Results', to: 'abc@abc.com'

            cleanWs()

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet?

Comment: I mentioned the Publish HTML parameters as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change path.

> HTML directory to archive   : ./newman

/newman